# Windows 7 - Can I "Make text and other items larger or smaller" different on separate displays? The selection applies to all 3 of my monitors

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I use three monitors.

One is my laptop, and the other two are large Dell monitors.

In the "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution" screen, I can change the resolutions of each screen individually, choose which I want to be my main display, etc. But there is an option "Make text and other items larger or smaller". It lets you choose from Small, Medium, and Larger.

Well, my Laptop screen is small, and compared to my other two monitors it is hard to read text on it. So I want to set that display to "Medium". But when I do that, it applies that adjustment to all 3 of my displays, and then the text on my other 2 displays is too big.

Is there a way to set only one display to "Medium" and let the rest stay "Small"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

not as far as I know, it's global.

Alternative would be to change the resolution on the laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of doing that on Windows 7 -- display scaling method is global for all monitors. However, Windows 8 does exactly what you want -- you can choose different scaling methods separately for different monitors. It also has a tool to scale different parts of interface independently (e.g. making only the text bigger but not the icons, etc.).

Hope this helps.